# How to get current user's id in cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

This [cloud code](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-v-how-to-make-friends/) to make friends worked in Parse.com.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("friend", function(request, response) {
    var userToFriend = new Parse.User();
    userToFriend.id = request.params.friendId;

    var roleName = "friendsOf_" + request.user.id;
    var roleQuery = new Parse.Query("_Role");
    roleQuery.equalTo("name", roleName);
    roleQuery.first().then(function(role) {
        role.getUsers().add(userToFriend);
        return role.save();

    }).then(function() {
        response.success("Success!");    
    });
});
```

But this wouldn't work anymore in the cloud code of parse-server, as there is no global current user.

I believe all I have to do to work with session tokens.  But I don't quite understand how to get the current user's id.

for example, in order to make the function above work I need to build the roleName with current user id. `var roleName = "friendsOf_" + request.user.id;`

I believe I need to use the sessionToken to filter for a query that belongs to the current user.

```
var token = request.user.getSessionToken();
var query = new Parse.Query('???');
query.find({ sessionToken: token }).then( ... );
```

Can I just do this:

```
var token = request.user.getSessionToken();
var query = new Parse.Query('User');
query.find({ sessionToken: token }).then( function(user) { 
    var roleName = "friendsOf_" + user.id; 
} );
```

Any advice would be appreciated,

Comment: What is the version of your parse-server ?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. It's `parse-server-example@1.4.0`

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the lack of request.user. I use it all the time. Perhaps your roles have CLP / ACL which prevents public read / write? They should. Maybe you just need to pass in master key, which *was* deprecated a bit. You used to be able to call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey`, which would implicitly pass master key to all parse methods. Now, you need to explicitly pass it, i.e. `roleQuery.first({useMasterKey:true}).then(...` or `role.save(null, {useMasterKey:true})`